# How can I use selenium to click accept all cookies on the website "sky news"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAbWv.png)

I want to make a web scraper for the news title on the news website, news.sky.com

The problem is, very often, the site will pop up a message to let me "accept all cookies" (see capture...)

I followed the guide on the similar question by using XPath. But, it feedbacks:

> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Seemly, selenium can't find out the location based on XPath.
so, is it possible to click "Accept all"?

please help, thx.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


e_driver_path = r"F:/Download/Portable Test/msedgedriver.exe"


# establish the web driver
s = Service(e_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)


driver.get("https://news.sky.com/uk")

# search = driver.find_element_by_id(ContentPlaceHolder1_NotifyBtn)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='notice']/div[3]/button[1]"))).click()

print("yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

The cookie buttons are in an iframe on that page. Here is one way of clicking that button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = "https://news.sky.com/uk"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='SP Consent Message']")))

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Accept all']"))).click()
    print('accepted cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')
driver.switch_to.default_content()
print('back to main content')
```

This will access the iframe, click the button, and then exit the iframe back to main content, and also print in terminal:

```
accepted cookies
back to main content
```

Selenium setup is chrome/chromedriver/linux, you just need to observe the import and the code after defining the driver, to adapt it to your own setup. Selenium docs can be found here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/